# Designing/Using a user table in Cassandra for account creation and login

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm starting off by designing a simple user table for account registration and login purposes. This is pretty simple:

Row key: time(); Columns: email, name, password.

Regarding this simple structure, I've a  question:

Here row key is a random one. How can I login by using email and password using php ?

Comment: you write a login form, which posts to a login script, which takes the login form data and matches it against records in the database. if there's a match, the user is valid and you marked them "logged in". As for the actual code to do that, that's your job.

Comment: Hi Marc B, Here row key is ramdom one. Without row key how can we match the records with posted data?

Comment: `where username=$username and password=$password`, basically. and don't use the time as your primary key. that's just silly. what happens if two users register at exactly the same time?

Comment: I am using phpcassa with codeigniter. I dont know how to write direct queries in codeigniter.

Comment: BTW - if you're doing this for a real web site, consider using g+, facebook or the like for your authentication. If you're rolling your own, there are many ways to screw it up and expose passwords to hackers.

Answer (score 7):

Cassandra takes a query-based modeling approach, so you could have the same redundant, denormalized data in separate tables...and that's ok.  You'll want to keep that in-mind going forward.

Registration and logging-in are actually two different things, so you're going to want to split those up.  Thinking long-term about queries and access patterns, it probably makes sense to split-up user account data from credential data, because credentials can change.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    userid uuid,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    email text,
    created_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE usercredentials (
    email text,
    password text,
    userid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
);
```

This way, when a user changes their password, they won't affect the overall `users` table.  Additionally, the frequency with which most users change their emails, an occasional delete (and thus, generated tombstone) shouldn't be that big of a deal.  This won't allow a `SELECT * FROM usercredentials WHERE email=? AND password=?` query to work, so you'll have to `SELECT password FROM usercredentials WHERE email=?` instead, but that removes the possibility of old passwords hanging around and causing potential issues.  You could argue partitioning on `email` and clustering on `password`, but that really doesn't make sense as an email would never have more than one password at a time (although you could design an additional table like that to store password history).

To keep track of logins, I'd advise something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE logins (
    time timestamp,
    userid uuid,
    email text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, time)
);
```

This would key your rows by a combination of `userid` and `time`.  The difference here, is that `userid` is the partition key, so all logins for each user would be stored together.  `time` acts as a clustering key, so that you could perform `ORDER BY` operations on it.  `email` is a payload field here, which makes sense because you can see it while also seamlessly grouping-together logins for a user who might have changed their email address.  That should cover the underlying tables.

For the coding side, the [CodeIgniter-PHPCassa](https://github.com/ianlivingstone/CodeIgniter-PHPCassa) project might be of some help to you.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have so much duplicate data. Like the email and userid, which has been used again in usercredentials and logins table.

Comment: @Srikan If you want `userid` to be returned on a query for `logins`, then you should have it in that table.  Otherwise, you'd need to make an additional query to get it.  That gets expensive in a distributed database, which is why building high-performing data models for Cassandra requires a different, non-relational way of thinking.

Comment: Probably when this solution was written still didn't exist the possibility, but instead of writing tables with duplicated data, you can use materialized views for this purpose.

Comment: @Menda Materialized Views are currently broken in all versions of Cassandra 3.x.  The newer versions mark them as "experimental" because the user list has seen so many complaints about them not functioning up to expectations.